# Is it not the waste of time to create abstract classes?

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

I am so confused about the abstract classes I know it is not a question related to programing problem.But this is the only place I can find solution for this.
As everybody know that abstract classes cannot be instantiated and you cannot implement anything in these classes. We can just derive these classes and can do implementation in derived classes. So my question is this:

**If we have to implement logic in derived classes and we have to use complete function and classes in derived class then why we create abstract classes?**

Can anybody give me a clear explanation for this? If there is any good example then please tell me

Comment: @MitchWheat I use it but did not find anything that explain it in a better way... But stack overflow have lots of experts that is why i ask better then google for developers :)

Comment: You searched the entire internet and couldn't find a single  explanation as to why abstract classes are a useful idea and how they are used? We must be using different internets.

Comment: _you cannot implement anything in these classes_. That is not true. An abstract base class can implement methods. And without any non-abstract methods an abstract class is very similar to an interface.

Comment: not entire but  I did not find any satisfied definition and explanation for this @MitchWheat

Comment: You might want to asking at [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), since this isn't really a code-specific program.

But yeah, I feel you. There's plenty of information on the web, but sometimes it takes hours to sift through it to find exactly what you want, when an expert on here could tell you in a seconds.

Comment: but what about abstract methods??? can u  implement anything in Abstract methods?? @MartinLiversage

Comment: Some things to send you in the right direction - abstract classes are not interfaces: in an abstract class you can implement functions. Interfaces and abstract classes are useful for *polymorphism* where you can have a list of an interface and the underlying objects do not have to be the same concrete type. That should help you find relevant info.

Comment: @mainrajput: No, abstract methods does not have any implementation. However, any non-abstract derived class must implement any base class abstract methods. However, not all methods in an abstract class have to be abstract.

Comment: okkk here is my question arise if abstract methods does not implement anything then why we define them ??? without any implementation what is the use of abstract methods???? @MartinLiversage

Comment: Since abstract methods are defined in the abstract class, your code can call them, without having to know the exact type of the dervied class. This way you can pass different derived classes to the same method requiring the base abstract type.

Comment: @mainrajput: One way to think about abstract methods is that the abstract base class says "I need this type of method but I do not know how to implement it. I leave this to my derived classes." So if the base class is `Shape` with properties `X` and `Y` it might declare the abstract method `Draw`. Then derived class `Circle` will draw a circle when `Draw` is called while derived class `Square` will draw a square when `Draw` is called.

Comment: okk again i stuck there if square want to draw its shape then why it ask for a non implemented function to base class?? square class can create its own function and use it I have to write the function in base class also and in derived class also ??? @MartinLiversage

Comment: @mainrajput: Because `DrawingCanvas` will contain a list of references to `Shape` objects. Now, `Shape` is abstract so the references in the list will actually reference either `Circle` or `Square` but `DrawingCanvas` does not care. It only knows about `Shape` and it knows that to draw the shape it should call the `Draw` method. Redrawing the canvas is simply a matter of iterating through all `Shape` references calling `Draw` which will then draw a mixture of circles and squares.

Comment: A pattern based on abstract-classes implementation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Answer (score 4):

When you use an abstract class you have some implementation in the abstract class, but leave bits that are specific to a derived class as abstract. For example, I might define an abstract class for all shapes:

```
abstract class Shape
{
  public int Sides{get;protected set;}
  public abstract int CalculateArea();
}
```

All shapes have a particular number of sides, so that can go into the general case (ie `Shape`). The calculcation of the area depends on the type of shape (triangle, square etc) so if belongs in the derived class. However, I'd like users of my class hierarchy to be able to call `CalculateShape` from any `Shape` instance.

How I create a derived class and override `CalculateLength`:

```
class Square : Shape
{
  public Square(int sideLength)
  {
    this.Sides = 4;
    this.SideLength = sideLength;
  }

  public int SideLength{get;private set;}

  public override int CalculateArea()
  {
    return this.SideLength * this.SideLength
  }
}
```

Note that I haven't reimplemented all of `Shape` in `Square`, I have only implemented the `Square` specific bits.

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150.aspx),

> An abstract class cannot be instantiated. The purpose of an abstract class is to provide a common definition of a base class that multiple derived classes can share. For example, a class library may define an abstract class that is used as a parameter to many of its functions, and require programmers using that library to provide their own implementation of the class by creating a derived class.

The above are all the technical explanation, in layman style it's like creating a blueprint that provide info what all things it can do, and all the derived  classes will provide there own process how to do that.
For example, we can think of `Driver` and we know there are many driver types like `auto-rickshaw driver`, `truck driver`,  `tractor driver` etc. but all have a common denominator functionality that is `Driving` but each of `Driving` process will be different, thus

> `Driver`: abstract class with `Driving` function
>   `Auto-RickshawDriver`: Derived class extending `Driver` class

Your question,

> If we have to implement logic in derived classes and we have to use complete function and classes in derived class then why we create abstract classes?

Just because we want to define some common functionality, that every other class has to abide to be member of it. In general term creating groups based on functionality, i.e. we can say if  that class belong to a group we are damn sure that those common functionality of that group will be present.

Comment: StackOverflow in an English language website. Please see [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes will contain common incomplete implementation which can then be reused from multiple derived classes.

- **protected** methods inside it can only be called from inside the derived classes.
- **abstract** methods need to be implemented in derived classes.
- **virtual** methods can be ocerriden in derived classes

In .NET framework you can find many examples of such abstract classes, e.g. [`System.IO.Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The code using all those classes can refer to them using their common public interface of `Stream`, not having to know which concrete `Stream` implementation it uses.

Answer (score 1):

Just to correct a minor detail, *abstract classes* can be partially abstract or fully abstract, depending on whether they are partially implemented (in which case we commonly call them *abstract classes*) or not implemented at all and have no member variable (in which case we commonly call them *interfaces*).

They are many uses for abstract classes, most of them implying the ability to extend behaviour of code without modifying this code.

Let's suppose that you want to write a program that reads data from the keyboard and writes it to the screen. (I'll use C# for the code, because it's slightly shorter than C++)

```
void Copy() {
  int c;
  while((c = Console.Read()) != -1) {
    Console.Write(c);
  }
}
```

Now, the requirements change. You want to be able to read from a file instead of the keyboard, depending on a variable.

```
TextReader reader;

void Copy(bool readFromFile) {
  int c;
  while((c = ReadNextChar(readFromFile)) != -1) {
    Console.Write(c);
  }
}

int ReadNextChar(bool readFromFile) {
  if(readFromFile) {
    return reader.Read();
  } else {
    return Console.Read();
  }
}
```

Now, you want to be able to read from the network. The `bool` becomes an `enum`, the `if`/`else` becomes a `switch`/`case` etc. etc.

```
enum ReadMode { FROM_CONSOLE, FROM_FILE, FROM_NETWORK };

TextReader fileReader;
TextReader networkReader;

void Copy(ReadMode readMode) {
  int c;
  while((c = ReadNextChar(readMode)) != -1) {
    Console.Write(c);
  }
}

int ReadNextChar(ReadMode readMode) {
  switch(readMode) {
    case FROM_CONSOLE:
        return Console.Read();
    case FROM_FILE:
        return reader.Read();
    case FROM_NETWORK:
        return networkReader.Read();
    default:
        return -1;
  }
}
```

And this can go on. And the same requests may occur for the writing. The problem with this program is that it explicitly lists all the ways you can read from a file. To read from another source, you have to modify the code (add a member to the `enum ReadMode` and add a `case` in `ReadNextChar`. You may deem this OK if you have access to the source code, but if it's an external library, you may deem crappy this way of doing because you can not extend this wonderful copy library.

Now meet abstract classes. What if you abstracted all the sources into a single `Source` concept, because after all, all you need is to ask the source for an `int`. So let's write this abstract concept.

```
interface Source {
  int ReadNextChar();
}
```

And all three implementations:

```
class KeyboardSource : Source {
  int ReadNextChar() {
    return Console.Read();
  }
}

class FileSource : Source {
  TextReader reader;

  FileSource(string path) {
    reader = new StreamReader(path);
  }

  int ReadNextChar() {
    return reader.Read();
  }
}

class NetworkSource : Source {
  TextReader reader;

  NetworkSource (string url) {
    reader = new StreamReader(path);
  }

  int ReadNextChar() {
    return reader.Read();
  }
}
```

And implement the copy function:

```
void Copy(Source source) {
  int c;
  while((c = source.ReadNextChar()) != -1) {
    Console.Write(c);
  }
}
```

Now any source type you want to add, you just have to implement a new derivative of `Source`, without modifying existing code. The `Copy` program remains correct and untouched, so do the existing derivatives of `Source`.

This is called *polymorphism*. If you look at the dependencies of the `Copy`, they don't include code concerning either files, network, or user interface. It can be packaged in a library, allowing users to extend the types of sources from which it can read.

Hope it's clear. The same can be done for the writing part.

Comment: Great answer but off topic. You extracted an interface which gets implemented by concrete readers, however the OP wanted to know about _abstract classes_ not _abstraction_ in general. If you would add some common methods to Source and make the ReadNextChar() method abstract, that would be on topic.

Comment: He says "you cannot implement anything in these classes", clearly meaning *fully abstract classes* a.k.a. *interfaces*, not *partially abstract classes*. Thus, the inroductory part of my post. Let the OP decide whether it's off-topic.

Comment: You chose the wrong language then, because an interface in C# is not a fully abstract class, it's an interface. A fully abstract class, would still be a class and it could implement one or more interfaces.

Comment: It *is* a fully abstract class, as far as design is concerned. It's a choice of C# to permit only deriving of one superclass. Note that the OP tagged the question "C#". I don't use abstract classes in C# precisely because you have only one ammo.

Comment: There is a semantic difference between an interface and an abstract class. Interfaces express intention and specific behaviour. An abstract class is just a base class, waiting to be inherited. Until a point, technically, you can substitute one for another, but that's not always desirable. And in your example, you just confirmed to the OP that there's no need for abstract classes, an interface is enough.

Comment: There is a need to distinguish interfaces from abstract classes in C# because the CLR enforces single inheritance, i.e. only one superclass. There is no need for an interface keyword in native C++ because the language allows inheriting multiple implementations, and in such a language, an interface is a class with only pure virtual public member functions with no fields. There is no *semantic* difference. It's just partial vs. fully undefined behaviour + the constraints of CLR.

Answer (score 0):

Regard this example:

```
abstract class A 
{
   // forces subclasses to implement
   abstract void method1();

   virtual void method2() 
   {
      // some common logic
      // that sublcasses can
      // modify
   }

   protected void method3()
   {
      // some common logic
   }
}

class B : A 
{
    void method1() 
    {
       // needs to be implemented
    }

    override void method2()
    {
       // optional: e.g. something added
       base.method1();
    }

}

class C : A    {
   //...
}
```

No you can specify common logic in the base class, as well as define abstract methods that every subclass will have. So your baseclass works like an interface. You can call `method1()` to every instance of B and C.

So: No! It's absolutely **no waste of time** ;-).

Answer (score 0):

It's not,

Assume you have a base class

```
class Foo{
   public String getGreetingMessage(){
      return "Hello " + getName();
   }

   public abstract String getName();
}
```

and you have a derived class

```
class Bar extends Foo{
  public String getName(){
     return "MeMamo";
  }
}
class Boo extends Foo{
   public String getName(){
       return "Boo";
   }
}
```

And in another class, I call the method from derived,

```
Bar b = new Bar();
System.out.println(b.getGreetingMessage());  // Hello MeMamo.

Boo boo = new Boo();
System.out.println(boo.getGreetingMessage());  // Hello Boo;
```

I don't need to write the base method all over again.
Assume that operation for another derived class.